# Using QGraphicsItem as key for QHash

Tags: qt, qhash

Before I embark into using this datatype and as I am a beginner in Qt, is it possible to use `QGraphicsItem` as key of `QHash`? It seems legal to declare something like:

```
QHash<QGraphicsItem*, someType> hashName;
```

So I guess it is something allowed.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly fine. Note that when you delete a graphics item, you should manually remove pointer to it from the hash.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense to do so as i guess the key is een as just a number, not areaal pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. But I'd use `QMap<QGraphicsItem*, someType>`, that doesn't make much difference, though. Also, you can inherit `QGraphicsItem` to attach data to items.

Comment: There is no point in using `QMap` here: lookup by key is slower in `QMap`, and ordering by pointer doesn't make any sense. Also attaching data to items is possible through `QGraphicsItem::setData` without subclassing `QGraphicsItem`.

Comment: I thought using hash requires calculating hash of key on accessing, iterating and inserting values (in `QHash` implementation, behind the scenes). Or hashing int/pointer optimized somehow?

Comment: Hashing pointers is trivial and is performed in Qt as `reinterpret_cast<quintptr>(key) ^ seed`.